# Joining one column of a data frame to an existing data frame of unqual length by common columns in each data frame

Tags: r, merge, unique

I have a large dataset (> 1 million records) from which I pulled Date, SiteID, SubstrateID, and WinterID. I call this `dailyWinter`. Below, I show only the first four records. Each date defines a WinterID. October is not winter, hence "NA".

```
        Date SiteID SubstrateID WinterID
1 2002-10-08  NW_SB           B     <NA>
2 2002-10-08  NW_SB           B     <NA>
3 2002-10-08  NW_SB           B     <NA>
4 2002-10-08  NW_SB           B     <NA>
```

I have another data frame called `dataSummary` (first four records below).

```
          Date SiteID   SubstrateID dailyMean   dailyMedian dailySD     dailyP05    dailyP25    dailyP75    dailyP95    dailyMin    dailyMax    dailyRange  dailyCount  dailyTH16   dailyTH18   dailyTH20
1   10/08/2002  NW_SB             B 29.7885     30          0.4737452   29.0705     29.395      30          30.3795     28.89       30.56       1.67        20          0           0           0
2   10/09/2002  NW_SB             B 29.8275     29.535      0.608278    29.215      29.26       30.37       30.94       29.08       31.13       2.05        36          0           0           0
3   10/10/2002  NW_SB             B 29.8680     29.63       0.5425591   29.26       29.44       30.37       30.76       29.26       30.94       1.68        36          0           0           0
4   10/11/2002  NW_SB             B 30.3838     30.095      0.8461519   29.44       29.63       31.18       31.72       29.44       31.72       2.28        36          0           0           0
```

I need the WinterID field from `dailyWinter` data frame included in `dailySummary` date frame but I want only one WinterID record for each date, instead of multiple dates (as it is in `dailyWinter` data frame). I tried using:

```
dailySummaryFinal <- merge(dataSummary, dailyWinterID, by = c("Date", "SiteID", "SubstrateID"))
```

This returned `dailySummaryFinal` which contained multiple dates with the same information because it was the same size as `dailyWinterID`.

How can I get the `WinterID` field in `dataSummary` so there is one row per date? I'm new to R and to this forum. Any help you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: `merge(dataSummary, unique(dailyWinterID), ...` ?

Comment: That did it. Such a simple little thing. Gets me every time. Thanks, eddi. How do I accept your answer?